# swt Table Viewer java keyboard shortcut for editing & moving between cells

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

I have an RCP application and I have an swt Table Viewer, one
of its columns is editable and I would like to be able to move in the table by using
the tab and editing the cells when pressing enter.
I saw the functionality before in some table viewers so I know its possible.

Any ideas how to do that? Is it some general binding in plugin.xml or it's specific 
to the viewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding a [CellNavigationStrategy](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/CellNavigationStrategy.html).
Have a look at [JFace snippet 059](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet059CellNavigationIn33.java).